# Is it safe and appropriate to remove SUID and SGID from certain system files in Debian 11 (files on the screenshot)?

Tags: debian, safety

The whole list of all files found with find / -perm -4000 -print and find / -perm -2000 -print commands (same) are on the screenshot. So is it an efficient and safe thing to delete SUID, SGID from all of them? Or it won't give any additional safety and just meaningless? Thank you in advance!

There is only one added user and we won't add any more users.

[List of found files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1QNm.png)

Comment: Changing the permissions on these files is a good way to wreck your system.

Comment: And please don't post screenshots of text you could just copy and paste. You are just making it harder for people to help you.

Comment: Okay, thank you, I won't use screenshots again.